# Function to yield treads make another function don't run correctly

Tags: lua, coregames

I create this function to work in CoreGames

```
-- Yields the current tread until the condition returns true checking every 'interval' seconds
function _G.WaitUntil(condition, interval)
    if not interval then
        interval = 1/60
    end
    local tread = coroutine.running()
    if tread then
        local function check()
            if condition() then
                coroutine.resume(tread)
            else
                Task.Spawn(check, interval)
            end
        end
        Task.Spawn(check, interval)
        coroutine.yield(tread)
    else
        error("Failed", 2)
    end
end
```

It worked to yield the spawn of a tank until the match was restarted, but not to yield the start of a round, because I wanted to yield the function `Game.StartRound()` but it didn't runned correctly, it runned but in that case the tread stopped.
I think it failed because in the first I added it in a EventListener and in the second I added in the main code,
First:

```
local function boolexpr()
    return _G.ActualMision == 1
end

Game.roundEndEvent:Connect(function ()
    -- Yields this function until the actual mission is 1
    if coroutine.isyieldable() then
        print("Restoring the tank")
    end
    _G.WaitUntil(boolexpr, 0.016)
    -- When resume
    Actual:Die()
end)
```

Second:

```
Game.playerJoinedEvent:Connect(function (player)
    if _G.IsInRound then
        Task.Wait(1)
        Events.BroadcastToAllPlayers("Show the select UI", player)
    end
end)

_G.WaitUntil(function () return #Game.GetPlayers() > 0 end, 1)

Task.Wait(5)

Game.StartRound()
```

Does this affect in something?